# How to overcome the the problem with Identity Fields and the Entity Framework for SQLServerCompact 3.5SP2?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

This question should be easily found on the net, but I failed:

I have an "ID" field on my SQLServerCompact 3.5 databasetable that has its Identity property set to True. When I manually insert values the ID column is incremented automatically. However, when I try to add records through the Entity Framework, I get an error message stating that "Server side generation of values is not supported".

How do I solve this (apart from upgrading to SQLServerCompact 4.0)?